# Parsing XML android throwing exception

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to parse the below XML in android but I am running into a problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServerInformation>
    <ConnectionInfo>
        <Command>ConnectToServer</Command>
    </ConnectionInfo>
    <Devices>
        <Device>
            <Hostname>Android1</Hostname>
            <IP>127.0.0.1</IP>
            <MAC>hello</MAC>
            <TCPSocket>100</TCPSocket>
        </Device>
        <Device>
            <Hostname>Android2</Hostname>
            <IP>127.0.0.1</IP>
            <MAC>helo1</MAC>
            <TCPSocket>200</TCPSocket>
        </Device>
    </Devices>
</ServerInformation>
```

I don't need to find the value of everything in the XML. I am just checking the hostname and the IP but when it gets to the MAC it throws an exception.

Below is the code I am using to parse the XML:

```
try
        {
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            xpp.setInput(new StringReader(xmlWriter.returnXmlOutput()));

            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            String tagName = xpp.getName();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
            {
                tagName = xpp.getName();
                if (tagName != null)
                {
                    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("Command"))
                    {
                        Log.d("Command", xpp.nextText());
                    }
                    else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("Hostname"))
                    {
                        Log.d("Hostname", xpp.nextText());
                    }
                    else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("IP"))
                    {
                        Log.d("IP", xpp.nextText());
                    }

                }
                xpp.nextTag();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("XML Exception", ex.toString());
        }
```

Below is the exception I am getting:

```
06-18 18:43:55.168: E/XML Exception(2134): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:TEXT hello@9:14 in java.io.StringReader@5271e300)
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Can you show the XML file? What you got up there is only a String.

Comment: Sorry forgot to format the XML so was being treated as HTML and hiding the tags

Comment: Just a tip, use if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){

Comment: @raybaybay Sorry, not sure what that's for, why and where would I use it

Comment: @Boardy: Using START_TAG and END_TAG will make it easier for you to identify the beginning and end of a tag, or else you'll have to keep track of it. You will notice that your tags are called 2 times: once for start and once for end. If you separate them in 2 if statements, it will be clearer which Start/End tag you're dealing with

Comment: you call nextTag when you should be calling nextText in the case of `MAC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the  `getText` method instead of `nextText` because you want the content of the tag, not the next text.

Also, use this format:

```
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
            tagName = xpp.getName();
            if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
                if (tagName != null){
                    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("Command")){
                        Log.d("Command", xpp.getText());
                    }
                    ...
                }
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
```

Add a root element, like `<Configuration>` that englobes the whole file.

Comment: Thanks for your help, driving me crazy for ages